# I need an explanation about the following unbounded function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Consider the set $E=\{2n:n=1,2,3..\}$. The set E is not paricularly sparse in N-every other integer belongs to E and this regularity is reflected in the size of the sum

$$S_E(N)= \sum_{m \in E, m \leq N}1/m= \sum^{N/2}_{n=1}1/2n=1/2(\sum_{n=1}^{N/2}1/n)$$

which is not a bounded function of N. To see this, first observe that for $n \geq 1$,

$$1/n > \int_n^{n+1} 1/x\text{ } dx$$

because $1/n > 1/x$ when $n<x<n+1$. It follows that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{M}1/n > \sum_{n=1}^M(\int_{n}^{n+1}1/xdx)=\int_{1}^{M+1}1/xdx=log(M+1)>log\text{ }M$$

for all $M>1$, and therefore

$$S_E(N)>1/2log(N/2)$$

Since $\lim_{x->\infty}log x=\infty$, it follows that $S_E(N)$ grows unboundedly with $N$

I need help with the previous procedure. The first thing that I need help with is why $1/n> \int^{n+1}_{n} 1/xdx$ is relevant and how it's true. I understand that if we can show that the size of the sum of the reciprocals is unbounded then the function is not sparse at all hence it goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

The statement that

$$\frac 1 n > \int_n^{n + 1} \frac 1 x dx$$

follows from the fact that for all $x$ in the interval $(n, n + 1)$, we have that $1/x < 1/n$. Monotonicity of the integral means that

$$\int_n^{n + 1} \frac 1 x \, dx < \int_n^{n + 1} \frac 1 n \, dx = \frac 1 n$$

---

The *relevance* of this estimate is that $$\int_1^n \frac 1 x \, dx$$

is easy to compute in closed form, while $$\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac 1 k$$ is not.

Comment: Let's start with your first claim. You claim that the statement t $1/n > \int _{n}^{n+1}1/x$ follows from the fact that all x in the interval $(n,n+1)$, we have that $1/x < 1/n$. I think I kind of get what you mean. The integral is basically the area under the curve and the area is equal to the sum of the area of every narrow strip that we can make. This is your $1/x$ right?, so if it's greater than the sum then it's greater than each summand or how can you explain it?

Comment: Yes, the geometric interpretation is that $1/n$ sits above the level of $1/x$, so it encloses more area under its graph - hence larger integral.

Comment: Now can you explain the part in which we have to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus I think?.

Comment: There was no application of the FTC in anything you wrote. What do you mean?

Comment: How did the final integral come out of the combination of sigma and other integral?

Comment: Because $\int_1^2 ... + \int_2^3 ... = \int_1^3 ...$, and applying that concept numerous times. Draw the picture of what area is being looked at if you don't see why.

Comment: got it thank you !!!!